# Moving support post holding up beam?

Tags: beam, post, support

MY Wife and I decided to take on some remodeling with the help of my plumber father in law. We moved the washer and dryer into the garage and re-ran the plumbing.

While looking at what it would take to remove the small wall to the left of the refrigerator I opened up the inside of the closet and found a pretty substantial beam above the ceiling. I think it's directly underneath the top of the stairs. The beam only spans  the closet, *64 inches*, and is only sitting on a single 2x4 sistered against another 2x4 that goes up higher on either end.

I realize now that taking out the beam is not going to happen. I essentially want to build a wall going back into the closet to allow a 60" set of base and upper cabinets to go where the fridge currently is and move to the fridge to the left of the little wall I'm going to build.

Can I add a 4x4 post 20 inches in, secure it to the concrete foundation  and secure  it with a strong tie to the beam above?

Also, I could use a steel corner bracket to attach the beam to the structure to the left of it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance,
Andy

Comment: Wow, that’s a pretty substantial beam. What is above the beam and how far do the joists span (on each side of the beam) that rest on this beam? What size is the beam? Is this a condo or apartment in a large building? Why the Fire sprinklers? Why the wood siding on the wall above the gypsum board in the last photo? Is the floor concrete slab? Do you know how big the footing is that’s under the existing post?

Comment: Don't touch it. Come up with another plan that doesn't involve possibly undermining the whole house. If you are dead set on doing this, you need to get the original structural blueprints for the house and have an engineer evaluate the proposed change.

Comment: To get a accurate idea of what you really have you need to remove the ceiling in the closet to see what is bearing on the plate above that beam.

Comment: @LeeSam From what we can tell the top of the stairs is the only thing above this beam and on top of that is the ceiling/roof  The joists seem to be 16 on center.  That beam seems to be a 4 x 10 that's 64" long. While it's technically a townhouse, it's completely standalone. This is also the reason for the sprinklers - all the units have them. it's on a concrete slab that is at least 4 inches thick, though I think it's slightly more than that given that it's 2.5 inches above the garage pour. The existing supports are sitting on top of a 2x4 that is nailed into the concrete foundation. cont p2

Comment: @LeeSam I believe that the wood above the short wall in the last pic is a joist running across the kitchen to the exterior wall.